# IT Returns for Capital Gains / India

Tags: taxes, india, capital-gain

DO I need to file IT returns if capital gains are under the annual limit of Rs. 2.5 lakhs and are the only the source of income?  Please advise.

Comment: Tax questions need a _country_ tag. India? Pakistan? Both countries use rupee as the name of the basic unit of their currency.

Answer (score 1):

If your Only income is Capital Gains and it is below 2.5 lacs and there is no other income...

Yes you are NOT required to file a return. However there could be queries as the buyer would have declared this transaction and the corresponding leg is missing in IT database.

Generally it is advisable to file returns even if you don't have to pay taxes;

- Income is more than 2.5 lacs, but you have investments covered.
- There is tax deducted and you need to claim refund
- You need to carry over some losses to next year
- You have been filing returns every year, its advisable not to skip for a year; more so if in the coming years you need to file again. It avoids queries from Income tax.